Want to know time complexity for rec Function
I tried to solve leetcode problem Select Cells in Grid With Maximum Score.
You are given a 2D matrix grid consisting of positive integers.
You have to select one or more cells from the matrix such that the following conditions are satisfied:
No two selected cells are in the same row of the matrix.
The values in the set of selected cells are unique.
Your score will be the sum of the values of the selected cells.
Return the maximum score you can achieve.
Constraints:
1 <= grid.length, grid[i].length <= 10
1 <= grid[i][j] <= 100

But it gives tle but max constraints only 10 × 10 grid, I think rec Function takes exponential time ,i want to know time complexity for rec Function also how to find time complexity easily for recursion.
The overall time complexity around n×m×(rec())


Class Solution {

    public int maxScore(List<List<Integer>> grid) {

        int ans=0;

        boolean[] hash=new boolean[101];



        for(int i=0;i<grid.size();i++){

            List<Integer> li=grid.get(i);

            for(int j=0;j<li.size();j++){

                int num=li.get(j);

                hash[num]=true;

                ans=Math.max(ans,num+rec(grid,i+1,hash,0));

                hash[num]=false;

            }

        }

        return ans;

    }



    public int rec(List<List<Integer>> grid,int i,boolean[] hash,int ans){

        if(i==grid.size()){

            return ans;

        }



        int sum=ans;

        List<Integer> li=grid.get(i);

        for(int j=0;j<li.size();j++){

            int num=li.get(j);

            

                hash[num]=true;

                sum=Math.max(sum,rec(grid,i+1,hash,ans+num));

                hash[num]=false;

            

        }

        return sum;



    }

}



Note that there are 1010 ways to select one number from every row in a 10 by 10 grid. This makes it clear that brute force is too slow.
Instead, observe that the number of rows is quite small—only at most 10. Thus, we can employ dynamic programming with the state being the actual rows used (represented as a bitmask). It is now only necessary to avoid choosing duplicate numbers, which can be achieved by first finding which rows each number appears in and then updating all the optimal answers in a single pass for each possible integer (in a similar fashion to the knapsack problem).
The time complexity is O(RC * 2^R) where R is the number of rows and C is the number of columns, which is fast enough.
public int maxScore(List<List<Integer>> grid) {
    var maxScore = new int[1 << grid.size()];
    List<Integer>[] occurrences = new List[101];
    Arrays.setAll(occurrences, i -> new ArrayList<>());
    for (int row = 0; row < grid.size(); row++)
        for (int val : grid.get(row))
            occurrences[val].add(row);
    for (int i = 1; i < occurrences.length; i++)
        if (!occurrences[i].isEmpty())
            for (int j = maxScore.length - 1; j > 0; j--)
                for (int r : occurrences[i])
                    if ((j >> r & 1) != 0)
                        maxScore[j] = Math.max(maxScore[j], maxScore[j ^ (1 << r)] + i);
    return maxScore[maxScore.length - 1];
}



I want to know time complexity for rec Function

First, you have to notice when you leave the recursion. Here, the only condition is i==grid.size(). Second, you trace that changes to i don't depend on other arguments, so we write total time as T(k,N) (k = N-i, N = grid.size() = li.size()). In that case, assuming List is an ArrayList, T(k,N) = const + N*(T(k-1,N) + const'). In this case, the expansion is easy: T(k,N) = c + N*c + N*N*c + ... + N^k*c = O(N^k). Or, in initial terms, T(i,N) = O(N^(N-i)).

also how to find time complexity easily for recursion

Notice how since N doesn't change between calls, what we got was a function of k: T(k) = const + N*T(k-1). The general case with recursion is that you check three things:

How much work did you need to do before recursive calls? (f(k) = const)
How many recursive calls do you need? (a = N)
How much do you reduce your argument per recursive step? (k-1)

In case of constant reduction, the result is dominated by all those products resulting in a^k (unless your f(k) is even larger but in practice it almost certainly is "too slow to be useful" either way, as you've observed). To make recursion practical, either the number of calls a must be almost always 1 (which gives you a loop in a different clothing) or the reduction in factor 3 must be multiplicative (for example, calling your function with k/2 or k/4).
There is an aptly-named "Master Theorem" for estimating the latter. Basically, when making recursive calls with k/b, the recursive part "sums up" to k^(log_b(a)) and if it's larger than f(k) then it is your complexity; if f(k) is larger then it is the complexity; and if they're equal then they sum up to k^(log_b(a))*log(k). Which is how all (good) sorting algorithms take O(N*log(N)).
